# The dimension of the solution space of two systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that the dimension of the solution space of two systems $Ax=b$ and $Ax=0$ is equal ($A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix). Please help me.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The space of solutions of $Ax=b$ is the affine space $A^{-1}b+W$, where $W$ is the space of solution of the associated linear system $Ax=0$.

Then the two spaces have the same dimension as affine subspaces of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$.